# Help with writing an Equation for area?

Tags: area

You have 240 feet of wooden fencing to form two adjacent rectangular corrals.  You want each corral to have an area of 1000 square feet.  So far I have a drawing of a large rectangle, split by a line directly down the middle.  This makes the 2 corrals with 4 lines representing length (the horizontal lines), and 3 representing width (the vertical lines). The equation for the perimeter of the entire corral is 4l + 3w = 240, and the equation for the area is (2L)(W) = 2000, or for each individual box it's LW = 1000. How would I write an equation for the area in terms of L? Also, how would you determine the possible dimensions of each corral by completing the square? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have two equations and two unknowns. How do you solve that? (The third equation is useless because it's just the second equation multiplied by two)

Answer (score 0):

Each corral has dimensions $ab$. There is an interior partition (length = b) shared by both corrals. So the total length of fencing $4a+3b=240$. Also, the area of one corral is $ab=1000$.
$4a+3b=240$
$ab=1000$
The top equation is a simple linear Diophantine equation with solution
$a=3c$ and $b=80-4c$.
Substitute these expressions into the bottom equation. This yields a quadratic equation in $c$. Solve it for $c$ and discard the negative value. Substitute the positive value of $c$ into the $c$-expressions for $a$ and $b$. Et voilà!
$a=30+5\sqrt6$
$b={{120-20\sqrt6}\over3}$